# Car sales fell 0.3%, but consumer confidence fell 3.8%, by what percentage did car sales outperform consumer confidence

Tags: percentages

It's been a while since I completed high school maths, and this one has me stumped. Sorry for the simplicity of the question.

**Basically, what I want to say is "whilst car sales fell, consumer confidence fell more.... car sales, last month outperformed the fall in consumer sentiment by X%"**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an initial hint to get you started before others give you the answer.

You want to find the ratio between car sales and consumer confidence. This ratio must be greater than $1$ because car sales *outperformed* consumer confidence.

Pay special attention to the word *outperform* because if car sales and consumer confidence were equal, or when the ratio between car sales and consumer confidence is $1$, the outperforming percentage is $0 \%$.

If car sales were at a level of $100 \%$ before, what percent are they at now? Similarly, if car sales were at a level of $100 \%$ before, what percent are they at now?

Putting everything together, the answer will be in the form $\frac{a-b}{c-d}-f$.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Toby. I had 4 figures written down before I cam here and one of them was the below, but 4% just didnt look right. 

((100-0.3)/(100-3.8))-1?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.